# Find a matrix A that satisfies data

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

I want to find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ that minimizes the following expression:-

$\sum_{i=1}^N ( \|Ax_i\|^2_2 - b_i )^2$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3}_{\ge 0}$, $b_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

Is there an easy (or standard) way to go about solving this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^N\| \|Ax_i\|^2_2 - b_i \|_2^2$, not clear why there is a norm, as $b_i \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, I think a square would do

Comment: Define $B=A^TA$ and your objective becomes $\sum(x_i^TBx_i - b_i)^2$. This is a linear least-squares problem in the 6 independent entries of the symmetric matrix $B$. Then $A$ is any matrix square root of $B$. (If $B$ is not positive semidefinite, some extra work is required.)

Comment: Thanks @Pebeto, I made the change.

Comment: @Rahul , Thanks, that makes sense. I am bit of a complete newbie, so was wondering how would you then solve for $B$? I am aware of how to solve for $x_i$, but I am not very familiar with methods to solve for $B$ when $x_i$s are known. Sorry if this should be very obvious.

Comment: @TonyJ, for any $x$, the expression $x^T B x$ is linear in $B$. Thus, you are getting a least-squares minimization problem. In fact, we have $x^T B x = tr(B x x^T)$, which is the inner product of $B$ and $x x^T$. However, the problem is not that easy, since $B$ must be symmetric positive semidefinite. You are getting an Semidefinite Programming problem, which you can solve using any solver you want (I personally prefer CVX or CVXPY). After obtaining your $B$, you can find its matrix square root $A$.

Comment: @AlexShtof: I naively assumed one could compute an unconstrained $B$ and project it to the PSD cone. Is there an easy counterexample showing that this does not give the optimal solution?

Comment: @rahul, I do not have an easy example, but also no intuitive reason to believe that it does work, not to mention a proof. I would not recommend doing something which I do not know to be correct.

Comment: It is easy to generate a counterexample (by just drawing some random examples)  for which the unconstrained solution has an optimal objective far below the psd constrained solution, i.e., the unconstrained solution can not (trivially) be projected to an optimal solution for the constrained case

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments, it can be cast as a semidefinite program. Using MATLAB and the modelling Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me) and some SDP solver (such as Mosek, Sedumi, SDPT3) you have

```
N = 100;
x = randn(3,N);
b = rand(1,N);
B = sdpvar(3);
objective = 0;
for i = 1:N
    objective = objective + (x(:,i)'*B*x(:,i) - b(i))^2;
end
constraints = [B >= 0];
optimize(constraints,objective)
A = value(B)^0.5;
```

The obejctive can alternatively be written as

```
((diag(x'*B*x)-b'))'*((diag(x'*B*x)-b'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Johan Löfberg! I will try this approach! Thank you everyone else for taking the time to help me as well! I appreciate it very much!